# Accessing page with expired session displays SQL error instead of index.

Tags: php, sql, session, yii

I have a page that should not be accessible if not signed in. The page works when there is a current session with the user but when there is no session, it throws an SQL error unlike the other pages that just redirect the user back to the index.

This is the exception being thrown:

```
   throw new CDbException(Yii::t('yii','CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement:{error}',
           544  array('{error}'=>$message)),(int)$e->getCode(),$errorInfo);
```

The stack trace then goes onto say that the SQL statement not being executed is found here under my components:

```
    function get_access($description,$action)
        {
           $party_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
           $accessType = (Yii::app()->user->isSubAdmin()) ? 3 : 2;
           $description = (Yii::app()->user->isSubAdmin()) ? 'Sub-admin' : $description;
           $membership_type = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT role_id FROM party_roles WHERE party_id = {$party_id}")->queryRow();
           $access = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT `{$action}` FROM access_rights WHERE description = '{$description}' AND access_type = {$accessType} AND membership_type = {$membership_type['role_id']}")->queryRow();
      if($membership_type['role_id'] == '1')
        {
           $access[$action]=1;
        }
        //echo $access[$action];
        // exit();
        return $access[$action];
     }
```

I then went on to check the actual page that's throwing me the sql error and this is where things get out of control:

```
         <?php 
if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('message')):
    echo '<script>alert("'.Yii::app()->user->getFlash('message').'");</script>'; 
endif;
         ?>
<div id="forum_main_box">
<div class="forum_header_box">
        <h1><?php switch_lang('Events', '博客', FALSE)?></h1>
     //error found here  <?php if(Yii::app()->partyroles->isAdmin() ||  (get_access('Events','add')|| get_access_advance('sub-admin','add'))):?>
        <a href="<?php if(Yii::app()->user->isAdmin() || (get_access('Events','add') || get_access_advance('sub-admin','add'))) {echo Yii::app()->createUrl('events/create');} ?>">Add New</a>
        <?php endif;?>
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
<br>

 <?php 

     $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_eventList',
    'ajaxUpdate' => false,
    'template'=>'{items}<div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div  class="pagination_box">{pager}</div>',
    'pager'=> array(
            'class'=>'CLinkPager',
            'header'=>'',
            'htmlOptions'=>array(
                    'style'=>'margin:4px 10px;'
            ),
    )
  ));

unset(Yii::app()->session['con']);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very likely that one or more of the replacement values in one or more of your queries are empty.  Since there are no quotes around the empty values your query or queries end up being invalid.

This:

```
"SELECT role_id FROM party_roles WHERE party_id = {$party_id}";
```

may be expanding to this:

```
"SELECT role_id FROM party_roles WHERE party_id = ";
```

This:

```
"SELECT `{$action}` FROM access_rights WHERE description = '{$description}' AND access_type = {$accessType} AND membership_type = {$membership_type['role_id']}";
```

may be expanding to this:

```
"SELECT `Events` FROM access_rights WHERE description = 'add' AND access_type =  AND membership_type = ";
```

Try wrapping *all* of your values in single quotes and try again, like so:

```
$membership_type = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT role_id FROM party_roles WHERE party_id = '{$party_id}'")->queryRow();
$access = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT `{$action}` FROM access_rights WHERE description = '{$description}' AND access_type = '{$accessType}' AND membership_type = '{$membership_type['role_id']}'")->queryRow();
```

Comment: Ouch. That hit the spot. I assumed that I didn't need those single quotations since some statements didn't need that. 

Anyways, thanks for the help. That was the answer!